# Como fazer migrations e versionamento com banco de dados firebird?

Tags: firebird, versionamento, migrations

Recentemente achei este site [Flyway DB](http://flywaydb.org/) onde, pelo que entendi, é possível criar migrations e controlar a versão do banco de dados. Porém acho que não suporta o Firebird. Existe alguma ferramenta similar com suporte ao firebird? Ou é possível usar o [Flyway DB](http://flywaydb.org/) de alguma maneira com firebird?

Comment: André, esse suporta o Firebird: http://www.liquibase.org/index.html (http://www.liquibase.org/databases.html)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: O liquibase pode atender a sua demanda?

Comment: Pelo que entendi me parece ser um pouco complicado de usar. Preciso estudar um pouco mais sobre ele. Mas eu usei o Entity Framework com SQL e me lembro de que lá eu criava migrations que continham as alterações feitas no banco. O liquibase segue a mesma ideia?

Answer (score 1):

Sim o liquibase segue a mesma idéia. Basicamente é criar changesets dentro do liquibase e executá-lo para que os updates sejam realizados.

Comment: Coloque o link do liquibase ou, melhor ainda, um exemplo de como fazer isto com ele :)

Comment: Alexandre podes completar a resposta aqui? basicamente explicando um pouco mais e dando exemplos?